# How to resort an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I have an array of objects that contains Albumes and i want to shuffle it when user re-open Album's screen.

So I write some function BUT it's just got one item Not All of them, So how can i handle it to return all items after shuffle it?

Albums

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "01- Out Life 2002",
      "company": "arabic rap",
      "avatar": "upload/Albums/1579652663.jpg",
      "artists_id": 3,
      "users_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-01-22 00:24:23",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-23 18:20:53"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "02 - First 2 Bomb - 2003",
      "company": "arabic rap",
      "avatar": "upload/Albums/1579803681.jpg",
      "artists_id": 3,
      "users_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-01-07 01:36:35",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-23 18:21:21"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Scormix 1",
      "company": "arabic rap",
      "avatar": "upload/Albums/1580658846.jpeg",
      "artists_id": 4,
      "users_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-02-02 15:54:06",
      "updated_at": "2020-02-02 15:54:06"
    },
]

  shuffle = arr => arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())]; 

  // just return One Item ~_~
```

Comment: The current `shuffle` function only returns a random element from the array, it does not actually shuffle the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is only returning one item accessed with a random integer, but you could possibly use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from the argument one!

Presumably you'll only want to show each album once, so I'd suggest an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array) to a similar question mentioning the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

It returns exactly what it's written there: a (single) item whose index is a random number. 
In order to shuffle the whole array you should iterate on the items, not just returning one item. Take a look at this post here:
[How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)